# separating string and Double Values on TextBox

Tags: c#, string, textbox, double

I Have `TextBox` And Textbox value come from database like this format  `$:2000.00`  so tell me guyx how to get only numbers on this `TextBox` on any `Double` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var input = "$:2000.00";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?");
var match = regex.Match(input);            
if (match.Success)
{
    double d = double.Parse(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thx Sriram Sakthivel give me any link of Rgex for studing

Comment: It goes wrong if double within the db response has an exponent or/and negative sign, e.g. "$:-12.34e56"

Comment: i think u give minus sign in Regex parameter

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx and http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: @naeemshah1 Updated answer for negative value also

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Updated for negative, I have no clue what are all the possible exponential number formats

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693831/datagridviewcombobox-column-dependent-on-another-datagridviewcombobox-column  any body Give me Answer This Question

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: Exponential part only is "[eE][+-]?\d+"; double is "[-+]?\d*\.?d+([eE][+-]?\d+)?"

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "$:2000.00";
var d = Double.Parse(s.Substring(2), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.   see my textbox value  Rs.:200.58

Comment: still not working check above answer its correct which will giving by @Sriram Sakthivel

Answer (score 0):

Try use Double.Parse method.[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following code

```
Double c =double.Parse(textBox1.Text.Split(":", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1));
```